# Unpacking the results of an sqllite3 call to format them in a string

Tags: python, sqlite

This is quite beginner but i'm struggling to work out how to format and results from a database call, i don't really know what to search and can't find a solution in tutorials
The calls return not as a list so i can't use indexes and i'm stuck

what i want to be able to do is change
`(2, 'Charmander', 'Fire', 'Basic', 'Common')`
to a format where i can use string manipulation to display it somethig like
`"{} | {} | {}".format(name, type, rarity)`
but like i said i can't iterate through the result as it's not an array

would i have to use splitting at the commas? that seems tedious
If you need any extra info let me know, thanks!

Comment: check the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html). An example of your code may be useful to better understand where you get stack and how to formulate a/the right answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row is a tuple. You can use unpacking assignment:

```
id, name, type, level, rarity = row
```

Comment: I Did Non Know it was that easy lol, ty!!

Answer (score 0):

Here two different ways to iterate throw rows in a table.

[Notice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#how-to-create-and-use-row-factories) that *"By default, sqlite3 represents each row as a tuple. If a tuple does not suit your needs, you can use the sqlite3.Row class or a custom row_factory."*

```py
import sqlite3

with sqlite3.connect(":memory:") as con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    # create table
    cur = con.execute("CREATE TABLE lang(name, first_appeared)")

    # populate table
    data = (
        {"name": "C", "year": 1972},
        {"name": "Fortran", "year": 1957},
        {"name": "Python", "year": 1991},
        {"name": "Go", "year": 2009},
    )
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO lang VALUES(:name, :year)", data)

    # perform query
    rows = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM lang")

    # format output
    apply_template = "{:<10}| {:4}".format

    # display output - method 1
    for row in rows:
        print(apply_template(*row))
```

Output

```
C         | 1972
Fortran   | 1957
Python    | 1991
Go        | 2009
```

alternatively you could use `fetchall`

```
    ...
    # perform query
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM lang") # no need to store the output
    ...
    # display output - method 2
    for row in cur.fetchall():
        print(apply_template(*row))
```

---

Maybe could be useful to adjust your `SELECT`-query to get only the columns that you want to format

```py
    rows = cur.execute("SELECT name, type, rarity FROM your_table")
    # format output
    apply_template = "{} | {} | {}".format

    # display output - method 1
    for row in rows:
        print(apply_template(*row))
```